# Alterantive to FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, airflow

So I found `FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` which helps in moving files from my local system to Google Cloud. But is there a similar airflow operator to move entire directory to Google Cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an official one, but it'd be pretty easy to create one, you can use reuse most of the logic from https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/file_to_gcs.py

You can use the same `GoogleCloudStorageHook` it is using to upload a single file and just iterate over the directory, uploading all the files. This is what any directory upload functions for GCS would be do anyway.

Depending on the amount of files you routinely need to upload, you might be better off breaking the upload into multiple tasks.  That way, should one upload task fail you don't have to restart the upload for all files. It depends on your use case though.

Comment: Thanks, never though of it that way. Sorry I can't upvote the ans as I have less than 15 points.

Comment: Np, glad I could help

Comment: @cwurtz why not submit a PR and share it with the community? new operators are welcomed.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't actually write a version of this operator, was just helping to point John in the right direction.